# how to add some variable data at middleware auth in register form?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I want to add some variable data to use at register form. something like option to select city. in normal controller i can do like this :

```
$data["city"] = City::selectOption();
return View('someView',$data);
```

How to add some variable data at miidleware auth in register form?

Answer (score 0):

first, In the app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php class, just add another variable.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'variable' => 'value',
        ]);
    }
```

the $data array on the create method is the $request variable from your get/post request.

second, in your App\User.php , add the variable to $fillable

```
  protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','variable',
    ];
```

for more info, take a look at
http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/09/25/adding-custom-fields-to-a-laravel-5-registration-form/